# Why $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM); is returning arrays with numeric indices ans columns name?

Tags: php, pdo

Trying to get array from database rows with numeric indices only with:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from resumenes";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    foreach ($stmt as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
```

I'm getting both, numeric indices and associative indices as if he had used PDO::FETCH_BOTH

Comment: Please check the code in your question. That's not how [fetch()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) should be used. Always put the exact code in your question that can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

3 possibilities :

1. Use `$row` returned by `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)` in a loot

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

2. Specify request fetch mode :

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM); // Fetch mode for this statement
$stmt->execute();
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

3. Specify default fetch mode, tipically after connection :

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```